# Cable Squats vs Smith Machine Squats

Tags: weightlifting, squats, cables

Are cable machine squats easier to do than squats on a Smith machine? I'm able to do about 220 pounds on the cables, but I'm doubtful whether I'll be able to replicate the results on a Smith machine. In terms of physics, I don't really see why they would be - both are assisted to some degree, but it seems to me that cables would actually provide less assistance since they are not rigid. Any ideas?

Comment: What specific type of cable squat are you doing? I've seen some that don't require you to support any weight at your shoulders, which would be a big difference between the two.

Comment: I'm holding the two handles at about shoulder length, with hands positioned the same way as if I was holding a bar there.

Comment: @JohnRoberts This question seems like an "experimental," since there is no data out there to say whether one is harder than the other.  With that being said, I suggest you to give a Smith Machine Squat a try to find out yourself.  I'm sorry, but I'm not able to find any decent literature out there to give you a firm answer.  I've tried both, and it seems like the squat machine is a little harder to me.  This is strictly a personal opinion.

Comment: Altho this remark is a bit remotely related to the question being asked, Id say both types of squats are easier than barbell squats, as there is less stabilization work involved.

Comment: I don't see how to correctly answer the question as it is currently a bit open and I don't see the practical application. As you have not tried both exercises yet, this is only a guessing game and invites for speculation. I think a better approach would be: "I lift 220 pounds on cables, but can only lift 190 on the smith machine, why?" (or vice versa).

Comment: Of interest: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15705030 Muscle recruitment patterns suffer, muscular imbalances develop, exertion is only a fraction of an actual squat.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the equipment that you are using.  Smith machines friction levels vary greatly and so do cable machines (along with their weight read-outs).  In general Smith squats should be harder.  Also I would never substitute regular squats with these and I would never recommend anyone to do Smith machine squats unless they were advanced.  It isn't a normal range of motion and can cause back, hip, knee problems.

Answer (score 1):

Things to take into consideration:

1. If the cable machine you use more than one pulley wheel, then your not lifting the full weight (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley)).
2. Unless you manage to get the cable almost vertical, you are not displacing the weight as much on a cable machine and so not producing the same amount of work (see [more wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29)).
3. Don't forget to count the weight of the bar on the Smith machine!

So you are probably right that the weight you can squat on a cable machine is likely to be more than on a Smith machine.

Comment: Even if it has one pulley it is not the same as full weight (or it could be more based on friction levels).

Answer (score 0):

They are not comparable exercises.  The cable machine squat incorporates your arms, while the smith machine will be pretty much all legs.